# Powershell is not installed in the system. Aborting

Tags: powershell

**I want to run a script but its showing this error:**

```
:MAS_Start

cls
title  Microsoft Activation Scripts AIO 1.4
set _elev=
if /i "%~1"=="-el" set _elev=1
for /f "tokens=6 delims=[]. " %%G in ('ver') do set winbuild=%%G
set "_null=1>nul 2>nul"
set "_psc=powershell"
set "EchoRed=%_psc% write-host -back Black -fore Red"
set "EchoGreen=%_psc% write-host -back Black -fore Green"
set "ErrLine=echo: & %EchoRed% ==== ERROR ==== &echo:"

::========================================================================================================================================

for %%i in (powershell.exe) do if "%%~$path:i"=="" (
echo: &echo ==== ERROR ==== &echo:
echo Powershell is not installed in the system.
echo Aborting...
goto MASend
)
```

[image]

But powershell is installed on my system

[image]

Comment: PowerShell 7 executable is `pwsh.exe`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have PowerShell (Core) installed. The Windows PowerShell, which the script is searching for in your `PATH`, would have the installation directory `%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` (so typically `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`). You could check manually, if it exists and contains `powershell.exe`.

If it is there, than the above directory is not in your included in your `PATH`. If it is really not installed, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell) for more information.